# why i am receiving this error ? django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: django, postgresql

I have created already postgresql database in my local and i already imported it in my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mytransactiondb',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

when i creating my database in pgadmin 4 i didnt encounter any password. then why i receiving this error?

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

here is my pgadmin 4

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One is connecting to the database 'postgres' and one to 'mytransactiondb'.  It is possible you have different authentication methods in your pg_hba.conf for those.  It is also possible you had previously told pgAdmin4 to remember your password.